# How Probability is related to Hash

Tags: hash, load-balancing, probability

Hashing is process of converting a data into hash value to provide more security to the data but what i'm trying to figure out is how can hashing and load balancing is related to probability .  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is two kinds of hashing:

- [Cryptographic (secure) hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), e.g. hashing passwords for security reason with a one-way hash function.
- [Regular hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), to (more or less) evenly distribute keys into buckets (which is basically the same as load balancing). Even with a good non-secure hash function, the probability of two entries to be hashed to the same bucket is low (for a very good hash function, 1 divided by the number of buckets).

The two concepts are somewhat related: a secure hash function *also* distributes well into buckets, but it is typically slow, and so not used for e.g. load balancing. A good regular hash function is much faster, and probability of collision is almost as low as with a secure hash function.